# Deploy ASP.NET App to Azure Web App without .NET Core and Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, xamarin-studio

I have a web application using some dependencies which will only run on .NET full framework, e.g. NHibernate.
So I cannot use .NET Core.
In addition, I only have Visual Studio for Mac, so I don't have a fancy auto-magic "Publish to Azure" button to deploy my app.

Any chance on just uploading the compiled ASP.NET application via FTP and run it on Azure?
Is there any howto on configuring the Azure Web App manually?

Seems like Microsoft only cares about .NET Core and assumes that all applications are easily convertible. I cannot find any docs besides "trivial index.html hello world via FTP" and "Use the VS publish button, done" articles.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Seems like Microsoft only cares about .NET Core and assumes that all applications are easily convertible.

This is far from true. All Azure Web Apps have the full .NET framework available.
[image: Application settings on the Azure Portal] Deploying a Web Application to Azure through FTP is simple. Have a look at [Deploy your app to Azure App Service using FTP/S](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-deploy-ftp)

In short:

1. Set deployment credentials
2. Get FTP connection information
3. Deploy files to Azure

One question I have: if you only have Visual Studio for Mac available, how are you building an ASP.NET MVC application running full framework?

**EDIT**
This resource might also be interesting: [Create an ASP.NET web app in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-get-started-dotnet) and of course **[Web Deployment Overview for Visual Studio and ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698.aspx)**

Comment: The linked resource exactly shows my problem. There's no information about how it internally works. I deployed them already via FTP. But how does Azure figure out which DLL to load? How does web.config come into play? 

To answer your question: It uses mono on mac, a classic ASP.NET project is supported out of the box.

Comment: It works like all ASP.NET web applications work: the wwwroot is the rootfolder of the application. If you put your web.config in the root, it's picked up by IIS. Based on which type of application you're developing the global.asax or startup class instructs IIS on which assembly to load.

Comment: Thank you, that is a vital information I was missing. It works by putting a web.config within wwwroot and register appropriate HTTP handlers.